# SQL query to return rows of ID's with dates as column from a particular date range

Tags: sql, mysql

Im trying to construct an SQL query which will return a shops orders per day from a particular date range, much like the below table:

|  | 01/10/2023 | 02/10/2023 | 03/10/2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 37 | 45 | 26 |
| 567 | 78 | 15 | 55 |

I have something very close which, however, its not quite right:

```sql
SELECT date(created_at), id, count(*) AS total_orders
FROM orders
WHERE created_at > '2023-10-01' 
  AND order_created < '2023-11-01'
  AND shop_id IN(
        123,
        567
    )
GROUP BY date(created_at), id;
```

This gives me the following:

| date(created_at) | ID | total_orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2023 | 123 | 37 |
| 01/10/2023 | 567 | 78 |
| 02/10/2023 | 123 | 45 |
| 02/10/2023 | 567 | 15 |
| 03/10/2023 | 123 | 26 |
| 03/10/2023 | 567 | 55 |

Is there a way I can format the results like the first table in the question?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Frequently asked - search fr mysql pivot and/or mysql conditional aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pivot for this. It will be a little complicated

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN created_at = ''',
      created_at,
      ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `',
      DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d/%m/%Y'),
      '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT created_at
  FROM orders
  WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2023-10-01' AND '2023-10-03'
) dates;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
  'SELECT shop_id AS ID, ',
  @sql,
  ' FROM orders WHERE created_at BETWEEN ''2023-10-01'' AND ''2023-10-03'' AND shop_id IN (123, 567) GROUP BY shop_id'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Please check [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GdJVk80t)

I have created sample data and you can run the script there

Sample input:

[image]

Sample output:

[image]